# Variable timestamp might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I have a class with two constructors - one accepts a `Date` object and the other attempts to create a date object based upon a given timestamp string. The caveat of this is that the conversion to a `Date` object can throw an exception. I'm getting the 'variable timestamp might not have been initialized' error.

First constructor:

```
public Visit(Date timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

Second constructor (the one that produces the error):

```
public Visit(String timestamp) {
    try {
        this.timestamp = dateFormat.parse(timestamp);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Visit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the initialization of `this.timestamp` to the `finally` statement of the `try` but this then gives an error that the variable may already have been initialized.

Comment: this.timestamp is final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy to use a default value when there is an exception, you can do something like:

```
Date temp = null;
try {
    temp = dateFormat.parse(timestamp);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Visit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

this.timestamp = (temp == null ? <some default Date value> : temp);
```

If not, then you could throw an exception from your constructor. Typically, if the argument of your constructor is not valid, you could rethrow an `IllegalArgumentException` for example.

Comment: Throwing an IllegalArgumentException works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could make the constructor "throws" the Exception, for example:

```
 public ToDelete(Date date) throws Exception {
    this.date = this.getDate(); //getDate throws the Exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried adding the initialization of this.timestamp to the finally statement of the try but this then gives an error that the variable may already have been initialized.

This is because a final member variable must be initialized in all code paths of a constructor and must be initialized only once. The only way to avoid this is to decouple the parsing logic from the assignment.